# Python 3 Scrape yellow Pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to scrape the data off of yellowpages but am running into where I can't get the text of each business name and address/phone. I'm using the code below, where am I going wrong? I'm trying to print the text of each business but only printing it out for the sake of seeing it right now as I test but once I'm done then Im going to save the data to csv.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#dont worry about opening this file
"""with open('cities_louisiana.csv','r') as cities:
    lines = cities.read().splitlines()
cities.close()"""

for city in lines:
    print(city)
url = "http://www.yellowpages.com/search? search_terms=businesses&geo_location_terms=amite+LA&page="+str(count)

for city in lines:
    for x in range (0, 50):
        print("http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=businesses&geo_location_terms=amite+LA&page="+str(x))
        page = requests.get("http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=businesses&geo_location_terms=amite+LA&page="+str(x))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
        name = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "v-card"})
        for name in name:
            try:
                print(name.contents[0]).find_all(class_="business-name").text
                #print(name.contents[1].text)
            except:
                pass
```

Comment: don't use `except:pass` because you can have error and you don't know it. At least use `except Exception as e: print(e)`

Comment: You're right because my code did have an error and I threw the try and except just to bypass it for.

Comment: @alecxe sorry about that. I just undeleted it and I am about to test it out. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should iterate over search results, then, for every search result locate the business name (the element with the "business-name" class) and the address (the element with the "adr" class):

```
for result in soup.select(".search-results .result"):
    name = result.select_one(".business-name").get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
    address = result.select_one(".adr").get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")

    print(name, address)
```

`.select()` and `.select_one()` are handy [CSS selector methods](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors).

Comment: Amazing. You've saved me again with this knowledge and it works perfectly. I'm glad to learn of different ways to get to the data. Thanks for your help!

Comment: How can I add the telephone?

Comment: @Kamikaze_goldfish same idea should work, locate the element with `.phone` CSS selector. Note that you should probably account for some businesses not having a phone number..

Comment: It's weird because I am basically copying the code and have added `telephone = result.select_one(".phones phone primary").get_text(strip=True, separator=" "` but with no success. I have even wrapped that in a try except to collect those without phones and everyone I scrape comes back empty or if I remove the try except I get a traceback error out of range.

Comment: @Kamikaze_goldfish you are not checking multiple classes correctly, should be `.phones.phone.primary`, or, you can check a single class only - `.phone`. Happy new year!

Comment: @ akexce THANK YOU! Where is the select_one documentation at? Is it part of beautiful soup or requests?

Comment: @Kamikaze_goldfish yeah, a part of `BeautifulSoup`, there is a link in the answer.

Comment: how can I grab the href data? I keep trying different variations but no success. Example = `<a href="https://agents.allstate.com/shane-n-sellers-abbeville-la1.html?cid=LDR-YP-CF-160615:MLP&amp;Campaign=222230000015670" data-analytics="{&quot;target&quot;:&quot;name&quot;,&quot;feature_click&quot;:&quot;&quot;}" rel="nofollow" itemprop="name" class="business-name" data-impressed="1">Allstate Insurance: Shane N Sellers<img src="//i1.ypcdn.com/ypu/images/icons/external-link.png?ef389a6" class="external-link"></a>`